# Twitter API auto authorize app without popup

Tags: twitter

currently using the Twitter API my users are prompted with a popup to log in with twitter and authorize the app.

I was wondering if there is a way to bypass that step (even if it's just a temporary unsecured workaround). For example, assuming each user uses the same twitter creds to authorize the app, can I hardcode the twitter creds in my app and have it not pop up to authorize each time? Or is there any other way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user must authorize your app to use their account.  In all cases, and in all circumstances.

You cannot hardcode credentials into the app, because apps are not permitted to authenticate to Twtter with user credentials.  There is no way around this, and it is by design.